# Library for Streaming Audio from Files

Tags: library, audio, .net, streaming

I am looking for a library which will assist me in streaming audio from files on my server to a client on a separate device. (Think Spotify.)

- The audio files at the source are very large, long, and lossless.
- The audio can (in fact, probably should) be compressed before sending.
- The client does not need to store any permanent file on the other end.
- Being able to seek within the stream is a must.
- The server side could be .NET C# or .NET C++. The client is written in .NET C#.

My current plan is to use an RTS stream (actually, VoIP), but this strikes me as a less-than perfect solution because:

- The stream doesn't actually need to be real-time since the audio source is a file. The client would benefit from being able to buffer.
- Playback controls would need to be out-of-band and homebrew.

Does anybody have any suggestions for an audio-streaming library?

Comment: When you say that the audio should be compressed before sending, does the quality of the compressed audio matter? For example, are you willing to accept a lower quality lossy-compression stream from the lossless file?

Comment: @MrPublic that is correct, quality is not important. thank you for taking a look at my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should take a look at [Opusfile](https://github.com/xiph/opusfile), which is the library used by the [Opus](http://opus-codec.org/) audio codec.

It supports lossy audio compression and [seeking](https://www.opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.6/group__stream__seeking.html), however you will need to create a wrapper for the DLL in C#.

This should be a good starting point in terms of an Audio Codec.

Comment: i ended up using [dr wav](https://mackron.github.io/dr_wav) to decode the audio file into PCM samples, transmitting those samples over a socket, and using [waveout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743876(v=vs.85).aspx) to play those samples directly on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

If a professional SDK is an option for you, take a look at LEADTOOLS multimedia library. (Disclosure: I'm a LEAD employee).

There's a .NET [Media Server module](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/media-streaming-server) that can stream audio, video or both.
The SDK supports various protocols, but for seeking abilities, you might end up using RTSP. Seeking may also depend largely on the client-side player. If it buffers adequately, you may be able to use the client buffer to seek back enough for your needs.

The SDK has more than one [audio codec](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/codecs), and depending on the protocol you choose, you might be able to perform encoding, compression and streaming in one process.

There's a free evaluation you can download, and tech support is free even during evaluation, so you can try and discuss your options before making any commitments.